# Why does this transformation of the system $x=z^2-y$, $z=y^2-x$, $y=x^2-z$, create new solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following system:
$\begin{cases}
x = z^2 - y\\
z = y^2 - x\\
y = x^2 - z
\end{cases}$

If we transform it by plugging in the variables at the end we get:
$\begin{cases}
x = z^2 - x^2 + z\\
z = y^2 - z^2 + y\\
y = x^2 - y^2 + x
\end{cases}$

If we try the solution $(1, 1, 1)$ for the first and second system, we can notice, that new solutions are created and I am not sure why. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: @HappyDay The variables seem to be right, and I've inverted the signs, because I am subtracting them in the original system.

Comment: What you showed is that any solution to the first system is also a solution to the second system. But if you start with the second system, you can't derive the first one. The very fact that $(1,1,1)$ is a solution to the second system but not the first shows that the two systems are not equivalent.

Comment: @roadrunner Thanks for explaining it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x=z^2-y\qquad(\text{eq}1)\\
z=y^2-x\qquad(\text{eq}2)\\
y=x^2-z\qquad(\text{eq}3)
\end{cases}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
$$
As I noted in the comments, your proposed transformation yields a new system which is implied by the given system, but the two systems are not equivalent.

To solve the given system, we can proceed as follows . . .

I'll assume you only want real solutions.

Then we have
\begin{align*}
&
y=x^2-z&&\bigl(\text{from }(\text{eq}3)\bigr)
\;\;\;\;\,
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
y=x^2-(y^2-x)&&\bigl(\text{using }(\text{eq}2)\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^2-y^2+x-y=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x+y)(x-y)+(x-y)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x-y)(x+y+1)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x=y\;\,\text{or}\;\,x+y=-1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so we can consider two cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;x+y=-1$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
&
x=z^2-y&&\bigl(\text{from }(\text{eq}1)\bigr)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^2=x+y
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^2=-1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so there are no solutions for case $(1)$, since we are only considering real solutions.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;x=y$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
&
z=y^2-x&&\bigl(\text{from }(\text{eq}2)\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z=x^2-x
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x=(x^2-x)^2-y&&\bigl(\text{using }(\text{eq}1)\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x=(x^2-x)^2-x
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^4-2x^3+x^2-2x=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x^3(x-2)+x(x-2)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x(x-2)(x^2+1)=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x\in\{0,2\}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x,y)\in\{(0,0),(2,2)\}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x,y,z)\in\{(0,0,0),(2,2,2)\}&&\bigl(\text{using }(\text{eq}2)\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and it's easily verified that the triples above are valid solutions.